# Page navigation with data retention in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

We are making a phonegap mobile enterprise app (a lot of information capturing and display) with almost 15 modules and using jQuery mobile.We are basically looking to navigate from say Page1 to page2 to page3 with back and next functionality and then submit at page3. Now when i navigate from page1 to page2 to page3 and then back, i want all my data to be maintained in the controls, How to achieve this? I am not looking forward to put all the divs (pages) in a single page purely because it becomes very congested, though We are using Single page implementation technique.

When i say data to be maintained, i mean, whatever data is filled in page1, is retained once i come back to the page after say navigating page2 and page3, i.e. fill Page1 next -> fill page2 next-> fill page3 back -> page2 (data retained) back-> page1 (data retained)

Comment: Good for you... You have an actual question?

Comment: AJAX, you don't navigate away from the page but have JavaScript handle request to the server for new data/update data/delete data or find data.

Comment: Please be clear.."i want all my data to be maintained in the controls." means? what is the exact question?

Comment: veger i have updated the question, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean preserve the state of the page, and don't want to keep it in the DOM. I recommend you [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org). The framework allows you the store your elements in separate View objects. You can freely destroy it from the DOM and throw it in later - with all it's "data" :) - whenever you want.

jQuery Mobile and Backbone do conflict a little. They overlap on the navigation mechanism, JQM is marked based, Backbone is programmatically. But you can easily resolve that. I prefer use Backbone for that kind of job. Here's how to disable  JQM navigation:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
  $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
  $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
  $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});

$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function(event, ui) {
  return $(event.currentTarget).remove();
});
```

I stole this from [Christophe Coenraets](http://coenraets.org) :P

And the rest, how to use Backbone for page navigation…, you should read [Backbone Documents](http://backbonejs.org)

You can use JQM as an UI framework. Backbone as an MV* framework. If you don't know how to use Backbone yet, you should learn it. It's worth your time :)

Comment: So, do i then need to do away with jQuery? i mean is it just a loading framework like requireJS?

Comment: You mean jQuery Mobile? No you can use it for your UI widgets. And no, not the same with RequireJS.

Comment: ok, so for UI - jQuery Mobile, for Navigation - Backbone. So i will go through Backbone then and let you know. Marking this as an answer till then.

Comment: Backbone is more than just navigation :)